# Ansible Jenkins plugin not working in GKE on top of docker/kubernetes - infinite loop

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform, jenkins, kubernetes, ansible-playbook

I have such simple playbook:

```
- hosts: 123.123.123.123
  tasks:
          - name: Jenkins - add job
            jenkins_job:
                    config: "{{ lookup('file', 'jenkins_conf/pipeline_staging.xml') }}"
                    name: deploy-staging
                    password: XXXXX
                    url: http://10.12.0.5:8080
                    user: someuser
```

When i will start it on Jenkins normally installed on server it is working. But when i'll try to connect to Jenkins installed in docker/kubernetes environment on GKE it is failing with:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to
>   validate if job exists, HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a
>   redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.\nThe last 30x
>   error message was:\nFound for http://10.12.0.5:8080"}

Here can be find some more details: [Ansible - jenkins plugin failing on Google Container Engine (GKE) - infinite loop with ingress](https://serverfault.com/questions/854820/ansible-jenkins-plugin-failing-on-google-container-engine-gke-infinite-loo?noredirect=1#comment1098565_854820)

I thought it could be because of my ingress/LB configuration but after i test it with remote execution with direct connection to Jenkins node im still getting infinite-loop error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is there actually a redirect configured on a web server as the error suggests?

Comment: There is only service exposed on NodePort